# Delete records by compound key over a limit

Tags: postgresql

Considering a table schema like so

```
id | user | target | timestamp
```

This table gets populated continually, but I only want to keep the last 10 records from any user/target combination. I'm fine to modify this while inserting, or as a task to purge records all at once or something in between, but I'm at a loss of how to do it. I know I can do something like

```sql
    DELETE FROM tableName 
    WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT id FROM tableName 
        WHERE user = 1 and target = 1 
        LIMIT 10 
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    )
```

But do that I have can only do 1 user/target combination at one. Is there a way to structure my query to remove ALL combinations with more than 10 records, or is there a way while inserting to sort of delete the latest as I insert.

Essentially I want to "log" only the last 10 entries. After messing around for a while I think this is close:

```sql
...WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT 
            id, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user, target ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS row 
        FROM table
    ) rows WHERE row > 10
)
```

This appears to get me the rows in excess of 10 for each "group". Does it seem to be doing what I think it is?

Answer (score 0):

That should do:

```
DELETE FROM tablename
USING (SELECT id
       FROM tablename 
       WHERE "user" = 1 and target = 1 
       ORDER BY timestamp DESC
       OFFSET 10) AS ids
WHERE tablename.id = ids.id;
```

This is one of the places where `OFFSET` has its use.

For speed, have an index on `("user", target)`, where the order doesn't matter.

Avoid naming a table or column `user`, because it is an SQL keyword.

Answer (score 0):

your attempt was pretty close

the following will delete all records older than the most recent 10 per `(user, target)` combination, ordered by `timestamp`.

```
delete from tablename
using (select
         id
       , row_number() over (partition by user, target order by timestamp desc) rn
       from tablename) as ranked
where tablename.id = ranked.id 
  and ranked.rn > 10
```

note however that `row_number()` will assign a distinct value for equivalent rows, i.e. two rows sharing the same `timestamp`. in the scenario where multiple rows can have the same age, one of the *tenth* rows will get kept, and if there are others, they will be deleted, and the choice of which row gets picked is not defined in your query. `rank()` assigns the same value for equivalent rows, so if you have multiple rows at the same age as the *tenth*, `rank()` would preserve them all. something to consider since you'll delete data that you might not be able to recover